# Compare and replace files using a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

Using a batch file you can do `fc folder1\* folder2\*`

Now, I'd like to extend that to support subfolders (assuming it doesn't already, idk), and additionally automatically move the missing files from `folder2` to `folder1`, but I don't really know how.

Comment: It's not clear what your ultimate objective is, but `xcopy /d /s folder2\* folder1\ ` will make sure that `folder1` contains any new or updated files from `folder2`. It is unclear why you would want to run `fc`, as this implies a manual decision about files, rather than a batch operation.

Comment: so `xcopy /d /s folder2\* folder1\` should do the trick? I thought you'd grab the content of fc and then run another batch file on them, that's what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine to use the native Windows [`Robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) command rather than `XCOPY` or `FC` which is *way more robsust* to complete your task than how you describe you're doing it. This is a simple and clear method using the ***Windows native*** `ROBOCOPY` commands from a batch script or command line. You can also check the log file for the exact files that were different and were copied over to the destination recursively afterwards.

If you're building something new, it'd be best to use `Robocopy` instead of `XCOPY` as `XCOPY` is a deprecated command intended to be replaced by Robocopy specifically per Microsoft as of Windows Vista (and newer OSes) I believe.

---

**Robocopy Script**

*(See **Script Note** below for options I used in this example and also be sure to change the sourcedir and targetdir variable paths where you need those set. Be sure to test from a test location as well just to be thorough and to confirm yourself before using for production purposes)*

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL
SET SourceDir=C:\SourcePath
SET TargetDir=C:\TargetPath
SET LogFile=C:\LogPath\Logfile.txt
ROBOCOPY "%SourcePath%" "%TargetDir%" *.* /PURGE /S /NP /R:5 /LOG+:%Log% /TS /FP
GOTO EOF
```

**Script Note**

*I used these options in my example but see below how to see all options to further suit your particalar needs.*

```
/S         :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
/PURGE     :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
/NP        :: No Progress - don't display % copied.
/R:n       :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
/LOG+:file :: output status to LOG file (append to existing log).
/TS        :: include source file Time Stamps in the output.
/FP        :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
```

---

**FURTHER RESEARCH AND DETAIL**

From command line in Windows, type in **`Robocopy /?`** and then press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

```
C:\Users\User>robocopy /?

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Dec 18 02:29:48 2015

              Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

::
:: Copy options :
::
                 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
                 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
             /LEV:n :: only copy the top n LEVels of the source directory tree.

                 /Z :: copy files in restartable mode.
                 /B :: copy files in Backup mode.
                /ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.
            /EFSRAW :: copy all encrypted files in EFS RAW mode.

  /COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                       (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
                       (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

           /DCOPY:T :: COPY Directory Timestamps.

               /SEC :: copy files with SECurity (equivalent to /COPY:DATS).
           /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).
            /NOCOPY :: COPY NO file info (useful with /PURGE).

            /SECFIX :: FIX file SECurity on all files, even skipped files.
            /TIMFIX :: FIX file TIMes on all files, even skipped files.

             /PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
               /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).

               /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
              /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).

     /A+:[RASHCNET] :: add the given Attributes to copied files.
     /A-:[RASHCNET] :: remove the given Attributes from copied files.

            /CREATE :: CREATE directory tree and zero-length files only.
               /FAT :: create destination files using 8.3 FAT file names only.
               /256 :: turn off very long path (> 256 characters) support.

             /MON:n :: MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
             /MOT:m :: MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.

      /RH:hhmm-hhmm :: Run Hours - times when new copies may be started.
                /PF :: check run hours on a Per File (not per pass) basis.

             /IPG:n :: Inter-Packet Gap (ms), to free bandwidth on slow lines.

                 /SL:: copy symbolic links versus the target.
::
:: File Selection Options :
::
                 /A :: copy only files with the Archive attribute set.
                 /M :: copy only files with the Archive attribute and reset it.
    /IA:[RASHCNETO] :: Include only files with any of the given Attributes set.
    /XA:[RASHCNETO] :: eXclude files with any of the given Attributes set.

 /XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.
 /XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.

                /XC :: eXclude Changed files.
                /XN :: eXclude Newer files.
                /XO :: eXclude Older files.
                /XX :: eXclude eXtra files and directories.
                /XL :: eXclude Lonely files and directories.
                /IS :: Include Same files.
                /IT :: Include Tweaked files.

             /MAX:n :: MAXimum file size - exclude files bigger than n bytes.
             /MIN:n :: MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes.

          /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
          /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
          /MAXLAD:n :: MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n.
          /MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.
                       (If n < 1900 then n = n days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).

                /XJ :: eXclude Junction points. (normally included by default).

               /FFT :: assume FAT File Times (2-second granularity).
               /DST :: compensate for one-hour DST time differences.

               /XJD :: eXclude Junction points for Directories.
               /XJF :: eXclude Junction points for Files.

::
:: Retry Options :
::
               /R:n :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
               /W:n :: Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.

               /REG :: Save /R:n and /W:n in the Registry as default settings.

               /TBD :: wait for sharenames To Be Defined (retry error 67).

::
:: Logging Options :
::
                 /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
                 /X :: report all eXtra files, not just those selected.
                 /V :: produce Verbose output, showing skipped files.
                /TS :: include source file Time Stamps in the output.
                /FP :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
             /BYTES :: Print sizes as bytes.

                /NS :: No Size - don't log file sizes.
                /NC :: No Class - don't log file classes.
               /NFL :: No File List - don't log file names.
               /NDL :: No Directory List - don't log directory names.

                /NP :: No Progress - don't display % copied.
               /ETA :: show Estimated Time of Arrival of copied files.

          /LOG:file :: output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log).
         /LOG+:file :: output status to LOG file (append to existing log).

       /UNILOG:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (overwrite existing
log).
      /UNILOG+:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (append to existing
log).

               /TEE :: output to console window, as well as the log file.

               /NJH :: No Job Header.
               /NJS :: No Job Summary.

           /UNICODE :: output status as UNICODE.

::
:: Job Options :
::
       /JOB:jobname :: take parameters from the named JOB file.
      /SAVE:jobname :: SAVE parameters to the named job file
              /QUIT :: QUIT after processing command line (to view parameters).

              /NOSD :: NO Source Directory is specified.
              /NODD :: NO Destination Directory is specified.
                /IF :: Include the following Files.
```

Comment: Thanks for that: I don't use Windows much these days, and I had always thought `robocopy` was third party software.

Comment: @AFH It sounds like it's third party but it's not, it's built into Windows. I use it for certain tasks and its just as integrated with Windows as xopy and copy. For future reference, xopy and copy still have their uses, but for much simpler tasks. I only use copy for force-copying individual files, for instance.